# regexpatch \xpatchcmd fails in patching command begins with space

Tags: patching, l3regex

The `\xpatchcmd` provided by `regexpatch` fails in patching command which begins with space. The same `\xpatchcmd` provided by `xpatch` works alright.

Some version info:

```
XeTeX      3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 
expl3      2018/06/14  
xparse     2018/05/12  
regexpatch 2018/05/02 v0.2d
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\test{source}
\xpatchcmd{\test}{source}{substituted}{}{\ddt}

% only this one fails
\def\test{ source}
\xpatchcmd{\test}{source}{substituted}{}{\ddt}

\def\test{source source}
\xpatchcmd{\test}{source}{substituted}{}{\ddt}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also commands that *end* with spaces. Not sure whether I'll fix this.

Comment: @egreg It seems an ending space won't trigger the problem now. I have provided an half-done answer, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by line

```
\tl_set:Nf \l_xpatch_replacement_tl { \cs_replacement_spec:N #1 }
```

inside the definition of `\xpatch_get_all:N`, in `regexpatch.sty`.

Since `f`-type always gobbles a space char (see doc of `f`-type from sec. I.1, `texdoc interface3` and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524726/79060)), the first line sets `\l_xpatch_replacement_tl` to `source` (instead of `<space>source`).
Using `\tl_set:Ne` instead of `\tl_set:Nf` may fix this problem.

The following redefinition of `\xpatch_get_all:N` seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn {Ne}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn {Nne}

\cs_set_protected:Npn \xpatch_get_all:N #1
  {
    % use \tl_set:Ne instead of \tl_set:Nf
    \tl_set:Ne \l_xpatch_prefix_tl { \cs_prefix_spec:N #1 }
    \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_xpatch_prefix_tl { } \l_xpatch_prefix_tl
    \tl_set:Ne \l_xpatch_arg_tl { \cs_argument_spec:N #1 }
    \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_xpatch_arg_tl 
      { \char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ } } \l_xpatch_arg_tl
    \tl_set:Ne \l_xpatch_replacement_tl { \cs_replacement_spec:N #1 }
    \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_xpatch_replacement_tl 
      { \char_set_catcode_space:n {`\ } } \l_xpatch_replacement_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\test#1 #2{ source }

\ttfamily
|\meaning\test| \par
\xpatchcmd{\test}{source}{substituted}{}{\fail}
|\meaning\test|
\end{document}
```

---

I did not fully understand why `regexpatch` uses `\tl_set:Nf` there yet. And I am not sure if the above solution will cause new problems.

Comment: `e`-type expansion is rather new (it was an emulation of `\expanded` introduced in TeXLive 2018, and then the `\expanded` primitive in 2019), so at the time `regexpatch` was written the only `f` and `e` existed (though `x` could be used there as well). I think `e` (or `x`) expansion is the right choice there (I don't see how it would cause any trouble).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks. I will write an email to the author of `regexpatch` about this `f`-type issue and deprecation of functions `expl3`.