# \tl_set:Nf deletes beginning spaces in its #2

Tags: expansion, expl3

In syntax

```
\tl_set:Nf <tl var> {<tokens>}
```

if `<tokens>` begins with a space (input as `~`), then this space does not appear in the definition of `<tl var>`. If a space appears in the middle or at the end of `<tokens>`, then it is kept in `<tl var>`.

Version info:

```
latex2e 2019-10-01
expl3   2020-01-12
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_test_tl

% \l_test_tl is set to "text", the beginning space is removed
\tl_set:Nf \l_test_tl { ~ text }
\verb|\tl_set:Nf|:~ |\l_test_tl| \par

% \l_test_tl is set to " text"
\edef \l_test_tl { ~ text }
\verb|\edef|:~ |\l_test_tl|

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: This behavior is duly documented. If you want to understand *why* it is this way, I suggest reading up on the “`\romannumeral` trick”.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469521/134574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f`-type expansion is documented as removing leading spaces: this is inevitable as it is implemented using `\romannumeral`. For *new* code, the `e`-type variant, which internally uses `\expanded` (or emulates it), avoids this issue and is usable in almost all cases that `f`-type expansion would have been used for in the past.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation `texdoc interface3`, sec. I.1, where `f`-type expansion is introduced at the first time (Thank @frougon for pointing this in comment):

> If this token is a `<space token>`, it is gobbled, and thus won’t be part of the resulting argument.

So an `f`-type expansion always gobbles the first space token.

Comment: Better yet, use `\tl_set:Ne`

Comment: @JohannesZ 1) Regarding the `\exp_not:N`, note that `\my_foo:f { \exp_not:N \c_space_tl }` does call `\my_foo:n` with a space token as its argument. 2) No more than one space token can be gobbled by `f`-type expansion. I don't see any place containing “removes beginning space(s)” in my version of interface3.pdf. 3) The fact is documented in I.1, precisely where `f`-type expansion is introduced: “If this token is a 〈space token〉, it is gobbled, and thus won’t be part of the resulting argument.”

Comment: @frougon I have added another example to my answer. 1) `\c_space_tl` and `\c_space_token` are different, see the first group of tests in new example. 2) The second group of tests in new example shows that two beginning spaces are removed. 3) You are right, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @frougon I forget that in latex, multiple consecutive spaces are treated as one.

Comment: @JohannesZ I know that `\c_space_tl` and `\c_space_token` are not the same thing. A space token is unexpandable, therefore doing `\exp_not:N \c_space_token` is **nonsensical**. OTOH, `\exp_not:N \c_space_tl` has the expected effect, that's what I said in my 1). :-)

Comment: @frougon The usage `\exp_not:N \c_space_token` is mentioned in the doc of `\exp_not:N`, so I just copy and paste them to initial version of my answer, without fully understandings.

Comment: I removed that "another example" mentioned from answer in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524724/tl-setnf-deletes-beginning-spaces-in-its-2/524726#comment1327334_524726). It can be seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/524726/8).

Comment: @JohannesZ Indeed, `\exp_not:N \c_space_token` is mentioned in the doc for `\exp_not:N`... precisely to say that trying `\exp_not:N` in despair to cancel the automatic removal of a space token at the beginning of an `f`-type argument is *not going to work*. I might be mistaken, but I don't see any good use for `\exp_not:N \c_space_token`.

Comment: @frougon Thanks for your kindly reply. I am not going to use `\exp_not:N \c_space_token`. They appeared in old versions of my answer just because I spot them from doc and then copy and paste without thinking "why they are there and what does that paragraph of doc want to emphasis". Your explanation have helped me get more understanding.